# Only keep __ most recent subfolders

Tags: file-management, automation, backup, directories

I have my blog backup plugin configured to send backups to a folder on my Google Drive. I am looking for an application that I can set to monitor that folder and delete all but the n most recent subfolders. I have found software that will do that for files, but not for folders.

Comment: Take care that your backup software is not doing incremental backups.

Comment: It's not. It's complete backups each time

Comment: I don’t know Google Drive. Does the solution have to interact with the Google Drive service, or is the Google Drive integrated in your filesystem (so it acts like a normal local folder)?

Comment: Google drive has a local folder with two-way sync. The solution needs only to work on the local folder and any changes will be synced to google's servers.

Comment: Do the date-modified timestamps of the directories measure what you mean by "recent"?

Comment: I suppose. That is what I mean by recent. When I used a Mac, there was a utility called Hazel that could do this. It's the only application I haven't found a Windows-equivalent for. The closest is File Juggler, but it only works in files, not folders.

Comment: If your question was answered to your satisfaction, you can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark under the voting arrows.

Comment: Tim, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The following Python script deletes all but the 3 most recently modified directories in another directory. Change the 3 to taste, and change `'mydir'` to the directory you want to operate on. Uncomment the last line to actually perform the deletion. It would be reasonable to first run it with the last line still commented out to ensure everything's set up correctly.

```
import os, shutil

dirs = sorted((f for f in os.listdir('mydir') if os.path.isdir(f)),
    key = os.path.getmtime,
    reverse = True)[3:]
for d in dirs:
    print("Deleting", d)
#    shutil.rmtree(d)
```

You can run this script regularly with a cron or anacron job on Unix-likes, or Task Scheduler on Windows.